# preselect item in unorganized list <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have a list of user options, one of which is a default determined by the system.

I have arranged these options as clickable items in a list. I would like the second item preselected, here is what I have tried in `JQuery` and `CSS`
**Jquery**

`$("ul > li:nth-child(2)").addClass("selected-state");`

**CSS**

```
.selected-state {
     background: #c24e4e;
}
```

`.selected-state` just mimics the behavior of the pseudoclass selectors active, hover and focus

this didn't work, none of the children have the background applied, but this may also be a factor of the `Vue.js` lifecycle, which is not the question I am asking about. I am hoping for inspiration for other ways to do what I am hoping for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just perfectly - you don't even need jQuery:

```css
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #c24e4e;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: brooooo..... so obvious after I made it this far. see thats exactly why I asked. I'm over here looking for lifecycle functions when I could have just put my css-foo.... INTO THE CSS

Answer (score 2):

Jack Bashford's answer makes the most sense to me, but if you are wanting to use jQuery you could use the following:

```js
var listItems = $("ul > li");
$(listItems[1]).addClass("selected-state");
```

```css
.selected-state {
     background: #c24e4e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option for jQuery. You can use `.eq()` method.

```js
function highlight(param) {
  $("ul > li").eq(param).addClass("selected-state");
}
highlight(1);//Pass param(number) to highlight your desire li.
```

```css
.selected-state {
  background: #c24e4e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it multiple ways there are:

**ONE**

```css
ul > li:nth-of-type(2) {
   background: #c24e4e;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

**TWO**

```js
$('ul > li:eq(1)').addClass('selected-state')
```

```css
.selected-state {
     background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

**THREE**

Use the next sibling selector using CSS

```
ul > li:nth-child(1) + li { background: red; }
```

**four**

```
$('ul > li:nth-child(1)').addClass('selected-state');
```

> **Note**: every answer is work for the same and CSS selector similar as jQuery selector you can try anyone.

**=== Thank you ===**